Nuxt 3 + ShadcnVue "Invalid configuration found in components.json."
I use Nuxt 3.3 and Shadcn Vue. When trying to install another Shadcn component via "npx shadcn-ui@latest add sheet" I get this error message; "Invalid configuration found in [MYPATH]/components.json.". It just stopped to work, days before it worked fine. I tried a re-install and init of ShadcnVue several times.
My components.json;
{
  "$schema": "https://shadcn-vue.com/schema.json",
  "style": "default",
  "typescript": true,
  "tsConfigPath": ".nuxt/tsconfig.json",
  "tailwind": {
    "config": "tailwind.config.js",
    "css": "assets/css/tailwind.css",
    "baseColor": "zinc",
    "cssVariables": true
  },
  "framework": "nuxt",
  "aliases": {
    "components": "@/components",
    "utils": "@/lib/utils"
  }
}


Any suggestions?
Regards, Alex

I wrongly used npx shadcn-ui@latest instead of shadcn-vue@latest
